# isset image upload php not working

Tags: php, image, upload, isset

Good afternoon, I'm having an issue with isset and !empty. When I try to upload an image, everything works properly. Now the problem is when I try to verify if isset or !empty on a file. It seems to not work really well. I think this is because $_FILES is different and doesnt work exactly like $_POST and $_GET.

```
 if (isset($_POST["submitpost"])) {
        if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            $newArticle = new Article();
            $newArticle->postArticle($idimage);
        }else{
              ....
 }
```

How can I verify if an image is not set? I want to edit a post and if it already has an image attached to it, user can either replace the image and add a new one or keep the old one. A reference is also added to the database in each operations. I also tried to use !is_uploaded_file as shown in the code above and it's also not working properly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$_FILES["file"]["error"]`
See the manual for fileuploads and specific [error codes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)